# undefined on server console after make-runnable-output

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a simple html application on nodejs. Here is the code os **server.ts**

```
import express = require('express');
import http = require('http');

import path = require('path');
import cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

export class Server {
    static startServer() {
        let app = express();
        app.use(cookieParser());
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

        let server = http.createServer(app);
        server.listen(7000, () => {
            console.log('Up and running on port : ' + 7000);
        });
    }
}
exports.startServer = Server.startServer;

// Call a module's exported functions directly from the command line.
require('make-runnable');
```

I have used `make-runnable` module to run exported functions directly from the command line. And this is my `start` script in **package.json**

```
"start": "concurrently \"tsc --watch \" \"nodemon server.js startServer\""
```

the application is working fine, but this is printing undefined on the screen that annoying and this should be solved.

```
[1] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[1] [nodemon] starting `node server.js startServer`
[1] Up and running on port : 7000
[1] --------make-runnable-output--------
[1] undefined
[1] ------------------------------------
[0] 4:08:52 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The `make-runnable` package provides you with the ability to clear the output frame by import the "custom" module and specifying a boolean value for `printOutputFrame`. Rather than `require('make-runnable')`, use:

```js
require('make-runnable/custom')({
  printOutputFrame: false
})
```

However, this doesn't remove the "undefined" (or output) message because `make-runnable` is expecting some return value to log as it resolves the promise.

**Instead, return some value from your function for Bluebird (or make-runnable) to print on its own:**

```
static startServer() {
        let app = express();
        app.use(cookieParser());
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

        let server = http.createServer(app);
-       server.listen(7000, () => {
-          console.log('Up and running on port : ' + 7000);
-       });
+       server.listen(7000)
+       return 'Up and running on port : ' + 7000;
    }
```

Note: I haven't verified that this won't cause the server to stop listening, but this is rather illustrating what the package will expect from your function.

## Explanation

*Bit of an older question but I came across the same issue recently so I figured I'd provide a solution.

The reason why "undefined" is being printed is that it's expecting some return value from the function that you're calling. Consider this snippet of a function (that I was working on and ran across this issue):

```js
generate: function() {
  // ... some preliminary code
  fs.writeFile(file, modifiedFileData, error => {
    if (error) throw error
    console.log('App key generated successfully.')
  })
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ node utils/EncryptionKey.js generate
--------make-runnable-output--------
undefined
------------------------------------
App key generated successfully.
Done in 0.27s.
```

By default, I just want that message to be logged to the console. Without `make-runnable` it worked fine since I initially just ran the function, but wanted to put this into an export. Looking at the source code (engine.js) for `make-runnable`, the following function:

```js
function printOutput(returnValue) {
  Bluebird.resolve(returnValue)
  .then(function (output) {
    if (options.printOutputFrame) {
      console.log('--------make-runnable-output--------');
    }
    console.log(output);
    if (options.printOutputFrame) {
      console.log('------------------------------------');
    }
  }).catch(printError);
}
```

**expects some return value, since Bluebird wraps the function you're executing as a promise.** I instead changed my initial code to:

```js
generate: function () {
  // ... some preliminary code
  fs.writeFile(file, modifiedFileData, error => {
    if (error) throw error
    return true
  })
  return 'App key generated successfully.'
}
```

and removed the "undefined" value, and printed my app key message.

Output:

```sh
$ node utils/EncryptionKey.js generate
App key generated successfully.
Done in 0.26s.
```